# Fold Razor Comments in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, razor, code-folding

I have large blocks of code in .cshtml file that are commented using the following syntax.

```cs
@*
    ...
*@
```

But Visual Studio doesn't show code folding option for this block. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a normal html comment around this as one solution.
Might not be the most elegant solution but it woorks.

```
<!--@*

    ................

*@-->
```